# Unable to get value of the property 'getWindowInformationInternal': object is null or undefined in CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

When I'm going to save the new Service Activity record, it will ask to Schedule the Activity and I clicked on 'Schedule' button.
If I logged-in to server through Remote Desktop Connection, its giving following error message:

> There was an error with this field's customized event.
>
> Field:crmForm
>
> Event:onsave
>
> Error:Unable to get value of the property
>   'getWindowInformationInternal': object is null or undefined

And I could see the JavaScript URL in IE debugger is: `https://orgURL/_common/global.ashx?ver=-1654397298`

But it works fine when I access it from outside the server(both are IE-9).

Can any one help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by clearing your internet cache/temp files and then restart the browser.

If that fails the next steps is to review this document: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh204512.aspx

Specifically the section about 'Configuring Microsoft Dynamics CRM Clients for Optimal Performance'.